# How to append two bytes in C

Tags: c

I am fairly new to programming in C and I have a problem that I have to fix. When I receive my data the most significant bit is printed like 00f1 and my least significant bit is printed 005e.
How do I get it so that the value can be 00f15e? 
As of right now I can only get them to print 5ef100

Comment: 1) those are bytes, not bits.  2) Show us code.  See [MCVE].  Also tell us the CPU you are running on; I suspect endianness may be in play here.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: `(a << 8) | b`. With some care not to shift signed/negative operands.

Answer (score 1):

Let's suppose that you are talking about bytes instead of bits, the MSB is 0xf1, the LSB is 0x5e and you want to get all together in 2bytes:

```
uint16_t result = ((uint16_t)MSB<<8) | (LSB);
```

(The number 8 must be replaced by a define in order to avoid magic numbers)

Answer (score 1):

Use bit ops:

```
#include <stdio.h>
typedef unsigned char uchar;
int main()
{
    uchar m=0xf1;
    uchar l=0x5e;
    unsigned ml=((unsigned)m)<<8|(unsigned)l; 
    //doing it in unsigned (at least 16 bits guaranteed, no sign bit)
    printf("%06x\n", ml); //prints 00f15e
}
```

Comment: However, this invokes undefined behavior on 8/16 bit CPU.

Comment: @Lundin Thanks. Fixed.

Comment: ...and no, changing to long does not fix it. `m` get integer-promoted to `int`, which is 16 bits on 8/16 bit CPUs. And then you shift 0xf1 into the sign bits, invoking undefined behavior.

Comment: I'm being stupid today. Made it unsigned and added casts (2 for good measure) on the RHS. Now it should be fixed.

Comment: Yep. Common bug on the mentioned kind of CPUs. This is where MISRA-C is useful.